# DATEDIFF hour option doesn't account for multiple days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two dates i need the difference in hours from

`2014-03-25 00:00:00.000` we'll call this field A

`2014-03-24 16:14:00.000` - (This is a calculated date with the hour and minute added) this will be fieldB

I do a 
`DateDiff(hh,FieldA,FieldB)`
and it returns a -8.
I would like it to return the number of hours from the whole day before.

When I run 2014-03-25 16:29:00.000 and 2014-03-25 00:00:00.000 i get 16 hours, which is correct

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  What result do you want if not -8?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're really asking for. 2014-03-24 16:14:00.000 - 2014-03-25 00:00:00.000 really *is* -8 hours. Why would it be 16 hours? What do you mean by "from the whole day before"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the difference in time, consider this:

```
DECLARE @d1 datetime = '2014-03-25 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @d2 datetime = '2014-03-24 16:14:00.000'

SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, @d1, @d2), @d1), @d2)
```

Comment: @rigamonk I just assumed Mikael Eriksson was right and used his output. if you give me examples for 10 different relevant values for 'd1' and expected result i will take a look at it, once I have the time

Answer (score 2):

Cast to time and do the datediff on time values only.

```
declare @D1 datetime
declare @D2 datetime

set @D1 = '2014-03-25 00:00:00.000'
set @D2 = '2014-03-24 16:14:00.000'

select datediff(hour, cast(@D1 as time(0)), cast(@D2 as time(0)))
```

Result:

```
16
```

SQL Server 2005

```
select datediff(hour, dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, @D1), @D1), dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, @D2), @D2))
```

Comment: i keep getting a 'Length or precision specification 0 is invalid.' When i switch it to a different number, it says 'Type time is not a defined system type.'

Comment: Ack. we're using 2005

Comment: @rigamonk Added a version for SQL Server 2005.